# Change tab bar item title and color programmaticaly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented a tab bar controller in my App Delegate, but it's just empty squares in the tab bar. I wish to could change title and images of them and also I want to know how use not only custom image I add, but "default" images implemented in Xcode ("calculator" image, "search" image).

If you have tab bar in a xib, you can see it in tab bar item -> attributes inspector -> Identifier, then there is a list, if you don't want to use custom images. So there is my `appDelegate.m` code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; // Override point for customization after app launch


    UIViewController *banksList = [[FailedBanksListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailedBanksListViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *listNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:banksList];

    UIViewController *first = [[BIDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BIDViewController" bundle:nil];    
    UIViewController *second = [[BIDDailyCount alloc] initWithNibName:@"BIDDailyCount" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second,listNavigationController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your `UITabBarItem`s your self.

In you appdelegate you could do something like:

```
UIViewController *banksList = [[FailedBanksListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailedBanksListViewController" bundle:nil];
banksList.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemSearch tag:0];
```

return self;

It might be a good idea to move this to a custom initializer in the controllers for each tab.

Comment: The system `UITabBarSystemItemSearch` *is* the image. I thought that was what you wanted. You set the title like you normally would: `banksList.title = @"List";`